# Entity Framework 6 children to parent relations

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework

Simple example:

```
public class Order
{
        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(128)]
        public string OrderNo { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Consigment> Consignments { get; set; }
}

public class Consigment
{
        [Key]
        public int ConsigmentId { get; set; }

        public Guid Identifier { get; set; }

        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

Now, What i want to do:

```
[...]
Order SomeOrder = GetOrdersBlahBlah();
Consigment consigment= new Consigment();
consigment.Identifier = Guid.NewGuid();
consigment.Order = SomeOrder;
_context.Orders.AddOrUpdate(SomeOrder);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

When i'm saving, no Consignment is saved to DB, and is not visible in consignments collection of order. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try it the other way: `SomeOrder.Consignments.Add(consignment);`

Comment: @Chris - yes, it this way everything work fine. But i need to use way i presented in question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are creating your consignment here:

```
Consigment consigment= new Consigment();
```

But you don't do anything with it. It just sits there, taking up space in memory, until your function goes out of scope.

You might think that the following makes the Entity Framework context aware of your consignment:

```
 consigment.Order = SomeOrder;
 _context.Orders.AddOrUpdate(SomeOrder);
```

But that's incorrect. Sure, `consignment` knows about `SomeOrder`, but `SomeOrder` doesn't know anything about `consignment`, and that's the one you are enrolling into the Entity Framework context.

You need to make the EF context aware of you `consignment` variable, either by this:

```
 SomeOrder.Consignments.Add(consignment);
```

or this:

```
 _context.Consignments.Add(consignment);
```